# Adding ROS2 to existing C++ Project

Tags: ros, ros2, c++

I have joined a project where we use a third party program that runs on another computer and sends messages via ROS2 (topics and services). Our goal is for our own code to be able to receive these messages, process them and also be able to send information back to the other program via ROS2.

However, our own program is embedded in a complicated framework and therefore cannot be built with colcon. Instead, makefiles are used.

My predecessors wrote two separate stand-alone ROS programs (one for topics and one for services) that convert the received ROS messages into C++ structs and write them to message queues with msgsnd, which are then read out in the main code. However, I would like to avoid this detour via the message queues for performance reasons.

My approach is to write my own small ROS library in which our ROS2 nodes with subscribers etc. are defined and then integrate this library into my main code.

I am currently failing to integrate this custom ROS code into my main program and wanted to ask if this is even a sensible approach before I try any further.

Many thanks and best regards